# Mongodb: Update Many documents with each element in given list

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I have this DEVICE collection

```
[
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60265a12f9bf1e3974dabe56"),
  "Name": "Device",
  "Configuration_ids": [
      ObjectId("60265a11f9bf1e3974dabe54"),
      ObjectId("60265a11f9bf1e3974dabe55")
  ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe64"),
  "Name": "Device2",
  "Configuration_ids": [
      ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe5a"),
      ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe5b")
  ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe65"),
  "Name": "Device3",
  "Configuration_ids": [
      ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe5e"),
      ObjectId"60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe5f")
  ]
}
]
```

I need to update all the documents that match the list of device ids. and push each element in a configuration_ids given list in each matched device. the 2 lists are the same lenght.

my solution is written in the following, but I can do it in one single query?

```
device_ids=[
        ObjectId("60265a12f9bf1e3974dabe56"),
        ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe64"),
        ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe65")
    ]

configuration_ids = [
        ObjectId("60267d14bc2f40d0dec1de3b"),
        ObjectId("60267d14bc2f40d0dec1de3c"),
        ObjectId("60267d14bc2f40d0dec1de3d")
   ]
for i in range(0, len(device_ids)):
   update_devices = device_collection.update_one(
       {'_id': ObjectId(device_ids[i])},
       {'$push': {'Configuration_ids': configuration_ids[i]}}
    )
```

The result:

```
[
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60265a12f9bf1e3974dabe56"),
  "Name": "Device",
  "Configuration_ids": [
      ObjectId("60265a11f9bf1e3974dabe54"),
      ObjectId("60265a11f9bf1e3974dabe55"),
      ObjectId("60267d14bc2f40d0dec1de3b")
  ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe64"),
  "Name": "Device2",
  "Configuration_ids": [
      ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe5a"),
      ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe5b"),
      ObjectId("60267d14bc2f40d0dec1de3c")
  ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe65"),
  "Name": "Device3",
  "Configuration_ids": [
      ObjectId("60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe5e"),
      ObjectId"60265a92f9bf1e3974dabe5f"),
      ObjectId("60267d14bc2f40d0dec1de3d")
  ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were hoping to use `update_many` to achieve this in a single update, then the short answer is you can't. `update_many` takes a single filter to determine which documents to update; in your example, each update is a different document id.

If you have a large number of these updates, and performance is an issue, consider using the [bulk write operators](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html).